# Disabled CTRL-ALT-DEL, ALT-TAB and Start Menu C#

Tags: c#

How can I Disabled <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> and Start Menu using this code. The code below is disabled <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

```
public class AltF4Filter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            bool alt = ((int)m.LParam & 0x20000000) != 0;
            if (alt && (m.WParam == new IntPtr((int)Keys.F4)))
                return true; //pang disabled ng alt f4                
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't do that

Comment: Guess that's for some presentation computer? Use group policies of the operating system to achieve your goal

Comment: You won't be able to disable Ctrl-Alt-Delete. That particular combination of keystrokes is part of the SAS (Secure Attention Sequence). The only way to over ride that is to write your own [Gina.DLL (Graphical Identification and Authentication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication). As Florian mentions, there are policies in the OS that can disable that.

Comment: @Icemanind GINA is only supported in XP and older, Vista and newer now  uses Credential Providers specifically to make it so you can no longer intercept the SAS..

Comment: Hello guys how can I disabled during run time of my solution ?